# GoogleAPIClient Deprecated - How to Implement New GoogleSignInOptions?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-api-client

I am working on a YouTube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAIErOevfoA), and I have gotten my map to work fine, however it is not showing the nearby locations. I noticed there was a line through `GoogleApiClient` and was told it has now changed to `GoogleSignInOptions`.

I'm fairly new to Android Studio, so I don't know really how to implement the new way into this code. I tried just changing `GoogleApiClient` to `GoogleSignInOptions`, but now getting more errors and I don't want to mess up what I have.

Here is the Java file with the errors, I have shorted this a bit, I am also getting one error further down on an if statement -  `if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {...}`

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleSignInOptions.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    GoogleSignInOptions mGoogleApiClient;
    double currentLatitude, currentLongitude;
    Location myLocation;

    private final static int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS_GPS = 0x1;
    private final static int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 0x2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        setUPGClient();
    }

    private void setUPGClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, 0, this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which errors do you get ?

Comment: No errors, builds fine.

Comment: quoting you: but now getting more errors and I don't want to mess up what I have.

Comment: Anyways, the GoogleApiClient has been indeed deprecated. Did you try using GoogleApi ? https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApi

Comment: Oh sorry, no errors in build, I am getting red text on `GoogleSignInOptions.ConnectionCallbacks`, `GoogleSignInOptions.OnConnectionFailedListener`, and `mGoogleApiClient.connect();`

Comment: Oh, okay I see some issues in that link you have sent.. Let me see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Check my answer with the migration guideline of google itself.

Answer (score 3):

Check the guideline on migrating here
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/moving-past-googleapiclient_21.html

Comment: Okay.. I have already written everything else out, and unsure where I would put everything after changing to the new way.. I might have to just find a more recent tutorial :( Thanks for your help though, but might be quicker to follow another tutorial..